# Como executar um método do back bean a partir de uma função JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

Estou desenvolvendo uma página Web com canvas em HTML 5, nela será apresentado dashboards em tempo real, para isso uso ManagedBean para retornar os respectivos valores, tenho um componente desenvolvido em `JavaScript` com sua variável declarada como global, e a cada 3 segundos deveria ser atualizado seus valores através do `pool` do Primefaces, porém isso não acontece, o código é executado uma única vez apos a renderização da página, como pode ser visto abaixo no código gerado:

```
<script id="j_idt2:j_idt3_s" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw("Poll", "widget_j_idt2_j_idt3", {
            id: "j_idt2:j_idt3",
            widgetVar: "widget_j_idt2_j_idt3",
            frequency: 2,
            autoStart: true,
            fn: function() {
                PrimeFaces.ab({
                    s: 'j_idt2:j_idt3',
                    f: 'j_idt2',
                    u: 'j_idt2',
                    d: 3,
                    onco: function(xhr, status, args) {
                        radial1.setValueAnimated(36.16220080628247);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Como faço para setar o valor do meu objeto chamando um método JavaScript com um intervalo de tempo em JavaScript através da chamada de um método do ManageBean?

```
<body onload="init()">
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />

    <h:form>
        <p:poll oncomplete  =   "radial1.setValueAnimated(#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste})" listener="#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}" 
                autoStart   =   "true"
                delay       =   "3"
                update      =   "@form"
        />              

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                    <canvas id="canvasRadial1" width="200" height="200">
                        No canvas in your browser...sorry...
                    </canvas>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </h:form>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

     var radial1;

    function init()
    {
        // Define some sections
        var sections = Array(steelseries.Section(0, 25, 'rgba(0, 0, 220, 0.3)'),
                             steelseries.Section(25, 50, 'rgba(0, 220, 0, 0.3)'),
                             steelseries.Section(50, 75, 'rgba(220, 220, 0, 0.3)'));

        // Define one area
        var areas = Array(steelseries.Section(75, 100, 'rgba(220, 0, 0, 0.3)'));


        // Initialzing gauge
        radial1 = new steelseries.Radial('canvasRadial1', {
                                         gaugeType: steelseries.GaugeType.TYPE1,
                                         section: sections,
                                         area: areas,
                                         titleString: 'Title',
                                         unitString: 'Unit',
                                         threshold: 50,
                                         lcdVisible: true
                            });

        // O método abaixo deve ser executado eternamente, como sugerido usando pool, mas o fato de estar em uma função JavaScript
        // aparentemente não é possível
        gauge.setValueAnimated(#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}` seria um template que retorna uma string? Será que não faltam só as aspas em torno dela? Verifique o console do seu browser para ver se está ocorrendo algum erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @bfavaretto o `#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}` é uma expressão do `Expression Language` do JSF, não é template não, roda em server-side. Eder, está usando alguma biblioteca de componentes? No Primefaces você poderia usar um `remoteCommand` para executar um método do `Bean` a partir do Javascript.

Comment: @Wakim Ok, mas então ele injeta algo no js que roda client-side, certo? Isso não geraria o erro de sintaxe que eu mencionei?

Comment: Ele injeta uma propriedade ou retorno de método, ai depende do tipo ou tipo do retorno do `teste`.

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância (se houver), mas você consegue chamar métodos server-side no client-side? Até onde eu sei, métodos do servidor são restritos ao servidor e métodos do cliente são restritos ao cliente.

Comment: @g.carvalho97, o client-side consegue invocar métodos do server-side sim. No caso ele executa uma requisição http (por Ajax ou Submit de form), o JSF interpreta (em suas fases) e chama o `action`, na quinta fase, correspondente no `backing bean`.

Comment: Senhores obrigado pelas respostas. O tipo do retorno do método teste é Integer, sim @Wakim, estou utilizando primefaces, preciso setar de tempos em tempos gráficos em `JavaScript`, a biblioteca SteelSeries, eu já havia pensando em usar o `RemoteCommand`, mas como isso se comportaria?  Uma vez que as requisições devem ser feitas a cada cinco segundos mais ou menos, e o retorno do método deverá ser atribuído a uma função JS que seta o valor dos gráficos que estão em Canvas

Comment: Você pode usar um `p:poll` pra fazer chamadas com intervalos. Ou o próprio `p:remoteCommand` usando a `serInterval` do javascript.

Comment: @Wakim, vou testar aqui, posto o retorno mais tarde. Obrigado!

Comment: @Wakim, identifiquei mais um possível problema, meu objeto é declarado dentro das tags `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Você precisa criar um javascript no facelets para chamar o que está dentro do script, talvez alterando-o.

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta mesmo, só formatar com 4 espaços.

Comment: Nesse caso você teria que usar o `oncomplete` do `p:poll` para atualizar esse objeto `gauge`. E ainda sim teria ter acesso a ele em outra função, talvez colocando como global ajude.

Comment: @Wakim, agradeço pelo empenho em me responder, estou quase desistindo, pensando em criar um serviço em Rest para atualizar com o Ajax, assim como no Exemplo http://www.desert-home.com/2013/06/how-to-use-steelseries-gauges-with.html, fiz o que você citou, reformulei toda a questão praticamente, dê uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18055/discussion-between-wakim-and-eder-f-freitas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução foi:

1. Usar o `p:poll` do primefaces ou um `p:remoteCommand` para invocar um `action` do Backing Bean.

   ```
   <p:poll autoStart="true" listener="#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}"
           oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" interval="3" />
   ```

   Ou com o `p:remoteCommand`:

   ```
   <p:remoteCommand name="atualizarUI" actionListener="#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
   ```

   No caso do `p:remoteCommand`, usando um setInterval para chamar a intervalos regulares:

   ```
   setInterval(function() { atualizarUI(); }, 3000);
   ```

   **Com uma atenção à função atribuída ao `oncomplete`, em relação a sua assinatura, que deve aceitar 3 argumentos (`xhr, status, args`)**
2. No Backing Bean, usar o `RequestContext.addCallbackParam` para retornar dados a função JavaScript usada no `oncomplete`, tanto do `p:poll` quanto do `p:remoteCommand`.

   Setando o retorno do Backing Bean para o a função Javascript:

   **Managed Bean**

   ```
   public void teste() {
       // Processamento necessário

       RequestContext context = RequestContext.getInstance();

       // Adiciona as variáveis para o JS (variável args da assinatura)
       context.addCallbackParam("nomeDoAtributo", "valor");
   }
   ```

   Tratando o retorno no JavaScript:

   **JS**

   ```
   function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {
       var nomeDoAtributo = args.nomeDoAtributo;

       // Atualizar UI
       gauge.setValueAnimated(nomeDoAtributo);
   }
   ```